# Menu links moves a little to the left when hovering with transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a CSS3 menu, everything is working great but when I set the `-webkit-transition:` to expand the width and margin in the menu, when I hover on the `ul` not the button it shakes a little like 1px the left till the end of the transition.

You can check it here:

> http://developers-community.com/beta/

Feel free to view source the website and go to the `style.css` as the menu is too big for jsFiddle.

Comment: try to put position for link absolute! relative position is causing such event to happen!

Comment: Nope, there's not any position relative out there...

Comment: if you don't define position then it takes relative as default! try to  put position absolute!

Comment: the menu just goes on the wrapper

Comment: tried it every where, it has the same error but it goes on the wrapper

Comment: when you use position absolute you have to define each and link position with top and left or bottom and right! by just putting position absolute! it will show all links in same line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed it, I used tables instead of the center tag and it got fixed!

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="my_menu">`

`<ul>`

`<li style="width: 98px;"><a class="menu" href="http://developers-community.com/">Home</a></li>`

`<li style="width: 98px;><a class="menu" href="about.html">About</a></li>`

`<li><a class="menu" href="#">Contact</a></li>`

`<li><a class="menu" href="#">Apps/Tabs</a></li>`

`<li><a class="menu" href="#">Web Services</a></li>`

`</ul></div>`

Add this....this will work

Comment: i dnt knw yr why it isn't working for you bt i tested it on my pc thts y put the code here!